# GLSL uniform array with size set by another uniform

Tags: opengl, shaders, glsl

Will the follwing GLSL code work?

```
#version 330

uniform int size;
uniform float[size];

void main() {
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The size of the array has to be a constant.

Specifically from the GLSL specification:

> 4.1.9 Arrays
>
> ...
>
> When an array size is specified in a declaration, it must be an integral constant expression (see Section 4.3.3 “Constant
> Expressions” ) greater than zero.